# Does a in-house iphone app have to go through the app store approval process each time it's updated?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Given that:

- my app is distributed only in-house with an enterprise-level membership
- my app is not sold publicly on the app store
- my app, after the initial distribution, will be updated frequently

Will it be required that someone from apple's app store reviews and approves the app each time I update?  Or can i just go ahead and release updates, without worrying about app review delays?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: Good point @AshishAhuja. This can be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to have your apps review and approved by Apple if they are distributed through the App Store.

For enterprise-level distribution you are in charge.